# Getting details of edited contact back using ACTION_EDIT and startActivityForResult()

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contentprovider, android-contacts, android-contentresolver

I am maintaining a list of contacts for my application. First I pick contact using `ACTION_PICK` with an `intent`. I am saving these contacts in my local database along with `CONTACT_ID`. Now user may choose to edit any contact to add some extra information that my app needs. I fire that edit intent with `ACTION_EDIT`. I have two questions here

1. I am saving `CONTACT_ID` to my database in order to use in edit intent. First question is does this id changes after edition ? because It so happens that I am unable to open contact editor for same contact again.
2. Second question is how can I read back all the details of this edited contact ? I am getting this back in my `onActivityResult()`. I have tried to use same code which i am using in case of picking but data structure returned in case of edit is different it seems.

Comment: Are you using android contact ContentProvider or do you have created your how ContentProvider?

Comment: yes I am using default one !

Comment: so you can use a cursor within your onActivityResult(), I will post a reply with source code.

Comment: @RicardoRivaldo thanks i will look at it when i get time and let you know

Answer (score 0):

you can get any data from contacts using a cursor like

```
String[] projection = new String[] {
     ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME,
     ContactsContract.PhoneLookup._ID};
// query time
Cursor cursor = _context.getContentResolver()
         .query("ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI",
                  projection, null, null, null);

if(cursor != null) {
    while ( cursor.moveToNext()) {
        String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(
                       ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME));
        // do other stuff
    }
}
cursor.close();
```

take a look at https://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-details.html